# Correct/Incorrect usage of delegates for achieving extensibility

Tags: c#, generics, animation, delegates, code-reuse

**I'm trying to give users of my GUI library unrestricted customization of in/out transition effects while still maintaining simplicity / preventing misuse** (for when a Control enters or exits the view).

To do so, I added a delegate to the Control class, which would take a Control reference and a transition-completion percent, so that the user would be able to smoothly translate a control's position / opacity in any way he wanted, based on the given percent. All he'd have to do is subscribe a transition function before control entrance/exit.

However, I realized it would be impossible to transition / animate the controls using only the current completion percent, because you'd have to store and compare the control's initial position as well.
**In order make this  storage requirement apparent, should I force usage of a delegate-functor?**

If so, how might I do that in a minimalistic / clean way?

---

**Feel free to suggest another way to allow users to apply custom transition animations!**

Comment: Could you paste some of the code you are using?

Comment: @MatthewRz It really wouldn't help with understanding =| It's exactly how I described it. I can tell you It's XNA and I'm modifying the Nuclex Graphics/GUI Library.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, your Control invokes Animation(calculation) delegate (from time to time, probably on each frame) and passes transition Competition percent. 
The Animation delegate then calculates and returns/applies translation and position to the Control. 
Is this correct?

Assuming that above is correct there are several solutions:

1. When animating only position and opacity:

   Beside competition percent, you must also send initial state of control's position and opacity when calling delegate. Initial state must be remembered on the transition start and sent into delegate in each call.
2. When animating arbitrarily properties in general:

   Beside competition percent, you also provide State property (type of Object or even better Dictionary). This State property is fully controlled by delegate and it's animation logic.

   To your Control, State property would not have any semantics or meaning. 
   Your Control only MUST retain value of State property between subsequent calls to delegate.

   Putting it all together, The Delegate fills the State with the initial values on the first call, uses these values on subsequent calls - does anything it wants. Delegate also applies calculated values to Control. Note that all properties that can be used in delegate must be public.

Answer (score 1):

IMO you don't have to provide the user of the control with the initial position of the control since he can position it relatively to the initial position:
negative numbers are for left and top, and positive numbers are for right and bottom.

The following code is a function for a fast transition:

```
Point FastTranDiagonial(float Percentage){
   Thread.Sleep(10);
   int pixelsDist = (1 - Percentage)* 300;//300 is the maximum distance 
   return new Point(-pixelsDist ,pixelsDist);
}
```

When you invoke the delegate you have to add the Point to the initial position of the control. You have to notice that the delegate contains a Thread.Sleep(X), this must be in control of the user since he might want to do a fast or a slow transaction.

You might also want to consider adding sequential transitions like jQuery so one transition starts after an other's completion.

good luck

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to pass in at least the following parameters to the delegate:-

- the control itself
- the container that contains the control (eg. a panel)
- the completion percent

By passing the control itself, the user will have all its initial state information (such as position). Also, if the user need to set any property of the control, he will definitely need the reference to the control itself.

The container may be needed by the user if he needs its size/position information, or if he needs to do something special to it for the control.